# Netty: Confused by threading behavior of Channel.writeAndFlush

Tags: netty

I am very new to Netty and I sill don't grok a lot of it. Here is something I find particularly confusing.

Channel.writeAndFlush is asynchronous: it should return immediately, before the I/O operation is complete. However, in the code below, the log statement in the listener ("Write operation complete") is always executed before the log statement after the call to writeAndFlush ("Returned from writeAndFlush").

Ok, that's fine: the I/O is fast and the listeners are invoked. However, the two log statements are always executed *on the same thread*.

So that seems to me that when I invoke writeAndFlush, that thread must be waiting for the I/O to complete then it is invoking the listeners. But how can that be if the method is supposed to be asynchronous?

```
private static class LoggingListener implements ChannelFutureListener {
    public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
      logger.debug("Write operation complete");
    }
}

public void writeAndFlush(Object object) {
  Channel channel = getChannel();
  ChannelPromise promise = channel.newPromise();
  promise.addListener(new LoggingListener());
  channel.writeAndFlush(object, promise);
  logger.debug("Returned from writeAndFlush");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Channel dispatches all the work to its `EventLoop` which is tied to an `Thread`, thus the `writeAndFlush` itself will be executed by a different `Thread` then your calling thread if you are not calling it from the `EventLoop` thread itself.

If you call `writeAndFlush` from the `EventLoop` thread it will just directly be executed and the future will be notified once it is complete which may be either directly or later on.